# QGIS not creating new profiles correctly

Tags: qgis

QGIS 1.8 is not creating new profiles correctly under `Documents and Settings`.

QGIS support files are also missing in `My Documents` for newly created profiles.

I just tried to copy the missing files from an existing working profile to a newly created profile and it was working fine.

However, at my workplace, people don't have a permanent workstation to work on and can log in to any system on the network.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

OS: Windows XP SP3

Comment: Strange.. actually its working fine on Win. 7 Ultimate 64 bit... Still we research and let you know..

Comment: Sunil thanks for your suggestion, but most of the people using the system for training purpose and they are all new joiners.

Comment: I might be wrong...but  you can create one fix user profile and try to use that profile across the network..OR Share some drive (Install the software on that drive) or files ..

Comment: @Sunil, Is [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roaming_user_profile) what you are referring to?

Comment: @blah238 Yes similar to this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Documents and Settings`, there is a `Default User` account folder. You may need to enable display of hiden and system files to see it. If you copy the `.qgis` folder of a working user into that, every new user on the machine gets this folder automatically.

For already existing users, you have to copy the folder manually (or write a batch for it).

Comment: @andre_Joost : Thanks for your posting. I followed your suggestion and every new user on the machine gets .qgis folder.However all the users getting this error.  An error has occured while executing Python code:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Documents and Settings/MohanBabu.RamMurth/.qgis//python/plugins\GeoCoding\GeoCoding.py", line 201, in geocode
    for place, point in result:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Python version:
2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit 
When i'm doing copy paste it was working fine.

Comment: What is the error ??

Comment: An error has occured while executing Python code:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Documents and Settings/MohanBabu.RamMurth/.qgis//python/plugins\GeoCoding\GeoCoding.py", line 201, in geocode
    for place, point in result:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
Python version:
2.7.2 (default, Jun 12 2011, 15:08:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]


QGIS version:
1.8.0-Lisboa Lisboa, 6416f38

Comment: I read from the blog http://www.stevencanplan.com/2010/automatic-geocoding-has-arrived-to-qgis/ that you must install geopy separately and you need a Google maps API key. If they are stored elsewhere on the computer, they are not copied with the .qgis folder.